# Laravel 5.2 - Error Upload and store file

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I'm working with `laravel 5.1`, I'm trying to upload a file by my form and move to folder images/user/id user, I'm trying like this:

VIEW

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('account/update/avatar')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    {csrf_field()}}
     <input id="input-upload-img1" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cambia</button>
</form>
```

MY CONTROLLER

```
public function updateAvatar(Request $request){        
    if ($request->hasFile('image')){             
        $username = Auth::user()->id . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->file('image')->move('images/users/', $username);
        $user = new User;
        $user->where('email', '=', Auth::user()->email)
                  ->update(['image' => 'images/users/'.$username]);
            return redirect('account')->with('message-success', 'success!');        
    }else{
            return redirect('account')->with('message-error', 'File error');
    }
}
```

ROUTES

```
Route::post('account/update/avatar', 'UserController@updateAvatar');
```

Actually it return -->

```
return redirect('account')->with('message-error', 'File error');
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding name to your input

```
<input id="input-upload-img1" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" name="image">
```

Comment: Haha, who was first?:)

Comment: I dont know guys!, but yes the issue is name! now it work! thank you! who is the first?

Comment: @Diego Cespedes 
Nobody know:) Glad your issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="input-upload-img1" type="file" name="image" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
```

Comment: who is the first?